# How to stop variable change inside StatefulWidget.?

Tags: dart, flutter

Every time setstate called, randomSel variable List get updated and I want to stop this

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyColorBook();
  }
}

class MyColorBook extends State<MyApp> {
  List randomSel = new List<int>.generate(16, (int index) => index + 1);
  var accepted = List<bool>.generate(16, (i) => false);
  initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it as a global variable by putting outside the class:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyColorBook();
  }
}

List randomSel = new List<int>.generate(16, (int index) => index + 1);
var accepted = List<bool>.generate(16, (i) => false);

class MyColorBook extends State<MyApp> {

  initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
```

or you can put that data in a class:

```
class Data{
    List randomSel = new List<int>.generate(16, (int index) => index + 1);
    var accepted = List<bool>.generate(16, (i) => false);}
```

and if you want to access that:
initialize Data:

```
Data data = Data();
```

and access the randomSel through:

```
data.randomSel
```

Comment: Thank you James. The problem was caused by (LIST.shuffle) which was inside the widget. Now how can I isolate this method and do it once after generating list?

Comment: can you give more information about list shuffle? Like some code perhaps ?

Comment: It is list.shuffle() method part of dart, used to scramble items order

Comment: apologies :)  it is my logic issue. Appreciate your support